# Cannot import using relative imports with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For some reason, I cannot get my relative imports to work for my python. My file structure and content is shown in the following image:

[image: File structure and content]

Then my `__init__.py` file is the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = 'database.db'

def creat_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "80aa3b5fb3563a688d51e6349d599f78"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

So when I run the script `main.py` it runs the `__init__.py` file but my db instance populates outside of the website directory and I cannot use relative imports "Because there is no parent directory".

I am not sure what is going on, so thank you in advance and if you need more info please let me know. Thanks